# google-play-services.jar separate download

Tags: android, admob

I am attempting to add google-play-services.jar to a project that uses ant.  From searching around I have found an older version of this jar file but don't seem to have the up to date version necessary.
Does anyone know where these jar files can be downloaded?

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the given below link and you can download the google-play-services jar file from here.

URL - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/google/android/gms/play-services-basement/11.8.0/play-services-basement-11.8.0.aar